# OS X - Indigo - 2.1.2 and 2.1.3 install problems

Tags: ros, rosdep, macosx, osx, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**I get this message after running 2.1.2 :**

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
python_qt_binding: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS [osx]
qwt_dependency: No definition of [python-qt-bindings-qwt5] for OS [osx]
rviz: No definition of [libqt4-opengl-dev] for OS [osx]
gl_dependency: No definition of [python-qt-bindings-gl] for OS [osx]
webkit_dependency: No definition of [python-qt-bindings-webkit] for OS [osx]
qt_gui_cpp: No definition of [qt4-qmake] for OS [osx]
qt_gui: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS [osx]
turtlesim: No definition of [libqt4] for OS [osx]

When I try the next step 2.1.13 ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

**I get this message:**

-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /Users/hector2/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH:
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/python
-- Using default Python package layout
-- Could NOT find PY_em (missing:  PY_EM)
CMake Error at cmake/empy.cmake:29 (message):
Unable to find either executable 'empy' or Python module 'em'...  try
installing the package 'python-empy'
Call Stack (most recent call first):
cmake/all.cmake:147 (include)
CMakeLists.txt:8 (include)

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/Users/hector2/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/catkin/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
<== Failed to process package 'catkin':
Command '['cmake', '/Users/hector2/ros_catkin_ws/src/catkin', '-DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/Users/hector2/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/catkin', '-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/Users/hector2/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated', '-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release', '-G', 'Unix Makefiles']' returned non-zero exit status 1

I would appreciate any help.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/262399/os-x---indigo---2.1.2-and-2.1.3-install-problems/) by [hector_dmg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30496/hector_dmg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-05-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You issue is that the qt4 dependencies that ROS Indigo needs are no longer available. I removed them in this pull request because the Homebrew formula they mapped to were no longer available or supported:

https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/14573

---

Unfortunately, I think ROS Indigo on macOS with Homebrew is a dead-end. Basically Homebrew has dropped support for Qt4 and despite trying to come up with all the dependencies they removed:

https://github.com/ros/homebrew-deps/pull/31

I failed to get that path to work out. At this point I think we're only going to be able to support a Qt5/Gazebo7/ROS Kinetic setup on macOS.

@mikepurvis basically came to the same conclusion:

https://github.com/mikepurvis/ros-install-osx/issues/63#issuecomment-293635361

See also:

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/504#issuecomment-292668534

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-05-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hector_dmg](https://answers.ros.org/users/30496/hector_dmg/) on 2017-05-23**:
:'(

Thanks for letting me know.